ASA reference doesn't work SQL DB and TIMESTAMP
i am new in Azure and try to check the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data
The idea was to simulate a stream from an SQL Database to use the windowsfunktion in Stream Analytics. My simple table is like following:
CREATE TABLE RandomData (
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Value1 INT,
   Value2 DECIMAL(10, 2),
   CreatedAt DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

The values are inserted with a stored procedure, all randomized and it works fine.
In Stream Analytics in the Snapshot-Window for, i insert the following statement
SELECT ID, Value1, Value2, CreatedAt
From dbo.RandomData 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @snapshotTime

It works. OK. But if i try to use the following, i get an error with the connection-check:
SELECT
  ID,
  COUNT(*) AS EventCount
FROM
  RandomData TIMESTAMP BY CreatedAt
GROUP BY
  ID, TumblingWindow(second, 10)

The error is:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.

If i delet TIMESTAMP BY, i see the next error with the Window-Function.
I cannot found any information whats going wrong. This is that, was i found in the article. Can anyone help? What is my mistake?
Thank you in advance
